# Unable to create model objects SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am beginner in web technologies and trying to write some flask based app

I am trying to create a relationship application.
Here the idea is Each test has to be part of one or more features and the features can have one or more tests.

I created following models in my application :

```
  app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'sqlite:///test.db'
  db = SQLAlchemy(app)

  FeatureTest = db.Table('FeatureTest',
      db.Column('Test_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('test.TestID'), primary_key=True),
      db.Column('Feature_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('feature.FID'), primary_key=True)
  )

  class Test(db.Model):
        TestID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        TestName = db.Column(db.String(250),unique=True, nullable=False)
        MouduleName = db.Column(db.String(250),nullable=False)
        ToBeExecuted = db.Column(db.Boolean,default=false)
        FeaturesPartOf = db.relationship('Feature', secondary=FeatureTest, backref='allfeatures')

        def __repr__(self) -> str:
              #return f'<Tests: {self.TestID}>'
              return f'<Task %r>' % self.TestID


   class Feature(db.Model):
         FID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
         Fname=db.Column(db.String(250),unique=True, nullable=False)
    
         def __repr__(self) -> str:
               #return f'<Feature: {self.FID}>'
               return '<Task %r>' % self.FID
```

All is fine at this point

But when I go for creation of the object for the models I get error

```
     (tutorialenv) PS C:\Users\am\Flask_Projs\CodeCamp> python
     Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
     Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
     >>> from app import db
     C:\Users\ashmishr\Flask_Projs\CodeCamp\tutorialenv\lib\site- packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default 
     in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
     warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(

     >>> db.create_all()
     >>> 
     >>> 
     >>> featureip=feature(FName='ipFeature')
         Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
         NameError: name 'feature' is not defined
     >>> featureip=Feature(Fname='ipFeature') 
         Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
         NameError: name 'Feature' is not defined
    >>>
```

I checked using a tool about my database status this is what I can make out

[image: DATABASE STATUS]

I am unable to figure out what is the problem here and request help.

Comment: You only imported the db module (and I guess created the database). You never imported app. As far as I know, you should not really be running a flask project in a python repl. Use Visual Studio Code or PyCharm - whatever your preferred IDE is.

Comment: Thank you @topsail.  Indeed that was the case. Just FYI, I am using VS Code only.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @topsail for pointing out the problem.

Indeed it was just an import issue.

I was trying to test my DB in the terminal of VS Code before writing some more code over the same.

As you suggested as soon as I import the other stuff it starts working.

Here is the snapshot

[image: Snapshot Depicting solution]